# asp.net MVC Validation order of operations

Tags: jquery-validate, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation, custom-data-attribute

I would like to know what the order of firing that occurs when you have a model property in an MVC application that has properties using the 'Required' Data Annotation and then is also validated against using the JQuery validator to decide if something is required based on user selection. In my current implementation, it seems that the JQuery validator **plugin** [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org) takes over when the user is interacting with the form.

So the scenario is that I want a date to be required only when a certain checkbox is selected. I have a Required Data Annotation on the field like so:

```
[Required]
public string SomeDate{get;set;}

public bool? IsDateRequired {get;set;}
```

Then in the JS file using the Jquery validator **plugin**, I have the following

```
$("#signupForm").validate({
            rules: {
                someDate: {
                    required: function() {
                                                  return isDateRequired; 
                                                  },
                })};
}
```

The end result is that SomeDate is only required when the isDateRequired is true. This is what I want to happen, I'm just not sure it's set up right.

If I do not have the DataAttribute 'Required' set on the Server Model side and the exact same JS code, it never fires the  validation. Is this because the JQuery validator does not set the "required" attribute on the input tag?

Comment: jQuery Validate is client-side form validation.  It is **not**  supposed to "set attributes".  It simply displays error messages and blocks form submission based on your setup.

Comment: See this page for basic usage guidelines:  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info

Comment: @Sparky... isn't the [Required] Data Attribute a client side validation as well?

Comment: Yes, all rendered HTML markup is "client-side" and I have no idea what ASP does with various HTML attributes, if anything.  However, I do know that the jQuery Validate plugin only ***reads*** them... it does not and cannot "set" them.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the act of making the date field hidden caused the field to not get validated even though the field is "required" based by the required attribute. Because of this, it appeared that the extra rules added to the ViewModel were overriding the data annotation, it is in fact just the way that jquery.validatior handles hidden fields. This makes sense since you as a user would get quite irritated if you had errors in your foem on fields you could not see :)

I guess I just assumed this was not done under the hood for you. There was actually no need for the extra rules at all.

Answer (score -1):

If you added the unobtrusive-validation.js to the page and applied the Data Annotation validation to the model class then you do not need to write jquery code to validate the form.

Comment: That would be true if it wasn't a conditional validation, but this is based on another value being set, so the Required attribute does not fit all scenarios. In doing some more research it looks like Jquery Validator is not setting the required attribute to required, but when I set the required annotation, it is set. Also, I am using this plugin  http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/    .. just to be sure we are on the same page.